# Swift 3 - view doesn't update when prepare for segue is called

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have an unwind segue which takes a few seconds to complete while it saves images to disk. I want to display an activity indicator until the view is dismissed but the view doesn't update.

This is my function, which is called from the view controller before it's dismissed:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "saveRecord" {
        print("indicator")
        let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        indicator.frame = self.view.frame
        indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
        indicator.color = UIColor.blue
        indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        indicator.startAnimating()
        self.view.addSubview(indicator)
        self.view.layoutSubviews()
        print("laid out subviews")
    }
}
```

The two print statements execute, and the debugger shows that the indicator has been added to the main view as a subview, but it doesn't appear on screen. Am I missing something?

I know the position of the indicator isn't a problem because running the same code in viewDidLoad correctly shows it in the middle of the screen.

**UPDATE**

I've recreated the segue functions using a delegate and it's saving everything correctly, but the problem remains. Still no activity indicator.

```
@IBAction func saveRecord(_ sender: Any) {
    print("indicator")
    let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    indicator.frame = self.view.frame
    indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
    indicator.color = UIColor.blue
    indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    indicator.startAnimating()
    self.view.addSubview(indicator)
    self.view.layoutSubviews()
    print("laid out subviews")
    saveImages()
    print("saved images")
    self.delegate?.saveRecord(name: name!, category: category)
    print("saved record")
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I'm really confused now! This starts the indicator:

```
@IBAction func saveRecord(_ sender: Any) {
    print("indicator")
    indicator.startAnimating()
    //saveImages()
    //print("images saved")
    //performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveRecord", sender: self)
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
@IBAction func saveRecord(_ sender: Any) {
    print("indicator")
    indicator.startAnimating()
    saveImages()
    print("images saved")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveRecord", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Have you called `performSegue` some where in your code?

Comment: Thanks Ahmad. Yes I've tried various ways of triggering the segue but I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the UI doesn't update until the saveRecord function has completed, but then the segue is called so the view controller is immediately dismissed. I solved it using dispatch queues - another new skill I've learned today!:

```
@IBAction func saveRecord(_ sender: Any) {
    indicator.startAnimating()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        self.saveImages()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveRecord", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use popViewController instead of an unwind segue. Then you have more control with a custom function on the back button.

What you can do then is:

- when you click on the back button (or save image button), add you indicator
- then save the image
- when the image is saved remove the indicator
- pop the view controller

Comment: Thanks. I still need to do things in the destination view controller, so I don't think this works for me.

Comment: Then use the delegate pattern for that. And also, Paulw11's answers is nearly the same thing what I suggest you ;)

Comment: Thanks again. After a crash course in the delegate pattern (which I hadn't used before), I've reworked it but I've still got the same problem - please see the updated question.

Comment: show me the save images function. the problem is, that you need to pop the view controller when you are really sure, that your images are saved. What you now do is: start the saving of the images and pop the controller immediately. It means, you are not waiting for the images to be saved. I know your images are saved, but this could happen in a background task, so you need to be sure, that the task is finished. How you save the images? To a server? coreData?

Comment: The save images function takes the image from UIImagePickerController and saves three different versions (high res, medium res and low res). The pop was only being called when that was complete. The problem was that the UI was not updated until after the save images and the pop had been completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update your views in `prepare(for:)`; the segue is already underway.

Rather than triggering the unwind segue directly from the UI element, trigger an action method that shows the activity indicator and performs the save and then calls `performSegue(withIdentifier:"yourUnwindSegueIdentifier", sender:self)` to actually perform the unwind.

Comment: Thanks, I see where you're coming from but how do I complete the segue actions in the destination view controller if there's no unwind segue? I'm puzzled by this as the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html says "You can also use the unwind action to update the current view controller before the unwind segue finishes.
"

Comment: You would still have an unwind segue; Ctrl-drag from the view controller icon to the exit icon, select the unwind method and give the resulting segue an identifier so that you can call `performSegue`

Comment: Thanks Paul. Again, I can get all the save code working using that approach, but my indicator still doesn't show.

Comment: What does `saveImages` do?

Comment: saveImages takes an image from UIImagePickerController, creates three versions (high, medium and low res) and writes them to the documents directory.